# how to print folder name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, filehandler

I am trying to read multiple folders for a specific text file using `glob.glob` to search in all folders. I wanted to print only the folder name instead of folder name/file.txt.

```
with open ('input.txt', 'w') as i:
    for files in glob.glob ('*/*.txt'):
        print (files)
```

I want my output to be like

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

instead of

```
folder1/file.txt
folder2/file2.txt
```

I saw many posts where they used os.path....which I did understand clearly

Comment: Use [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname).

Answer (score 1):

Solve this with ***string functions***. Try this code.

```
with open ('input.txt', 'w') as i:
    for files in glob.glob ('*/*.txt'):
        print(files.split("/")[0])
```

**Explanation:**

We are splitting the filename with `/` character. This results in a list with two items folder_name and file_name. Using indexing, we are fetching the first item with index `0`.

To test this try below code -

```
a = [ "folder1/file.txt", "folder2/file.txt"]
for item in a:
    print(item.split("/")[0])
```